# how suppress Applet java alert

Tags: java, applet

Good Morning.
I have a problem with my web app. The app works perfectly but it is stopped two times by popup of java and i want suppress it.
The app consultes a bbdd when i press a button and here is when appear the first popup like this;

[image]

If i press allow button then appear the second applet alert like this,

[image]

Any idea??

thanks!!

Comment: well as you seem to be running tomcat, then get rid of this 20 year old dead technology and write in using some newer

Comment: Yes, idea: applets are dead. Browsers don't like them any more (depending on the browswer type, for **years**). Forget about applets; and spend your time learning technology that has more value to offer than a lesson in "computer science history of the past".

Comment: See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).